# Typewrite command of pyautogui module is not giving desired output

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyautogui

I working with pyautogui module and performed following steps:

1. imported pyautogui.
2. gave `pyautogui.hotkey('winleft')`

Worked properly and window popped up. Now I want to launch chrome.

3. Gave command `pyautogui.typewrite('chrome\n')`

Instead of launching chrome , it is typing on IDLE panel as chrome.

Kindly help how to resolve this Because I want to launch chrome.

OS: windows 10
Python version: 3.8.1

Comment: Please show the code

Answer (score 0):

```
import webbrowser

url = 'about:blank'

# MacOS
#chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'

# Windows
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

# Linux
# chrome_path = '/usr/bin/google-chrome %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```